React page not showing when there is an error. Is there a way to see the error?
React page is not showing when there is an error, is there any method that we can use to see the actual error?
Trying to build a simple lottery game in React, in which user can buy a new ticket. If the sum of tickets is equal to 15, a confetti effect will be triggered, which will display the text "Winner".  Otherwise, the text "Loser" will be shown.
But the page is not rendering, and I cannot see any error messages.
Here's the code:
import { getTicket, sum } from "./helper";
import "./Lottery.css";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import party from "party-js";

export default function Lottery() {
    let [ticket, setTicket] = useState(getTicket(3));
    let isWining = sum(ticket);
    const winnerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isWining === 15) {
            party.confetti(winnerRef.current, {
                count: party.variation.range(60, 90),
            });
        }
    }, [isWining]);
    
    let newTicket = () => {
        setTicket(getTicket(3));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>This is a lottery game</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="Ticket">
                <span>{ticket[0]}</span>
                <span>{ticket[1]}</span>
                <span>{ticket[2]}</span>
            </div>
            {isWining === 15 ?
                <p ref={winnerRef}>Winner</p> :
                <p>Loser</p>}
            <div>
                <button onClick={newTicket}>Buy New Ticket</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


Expected Behavior:

Page should display lottery numbers and show if the user is a winner or a loser.
If user wins, confetti should appear.

Actual Behavior:

The page is not rendering, and I can't see any error messages.


have you heard of the browser developer tools console?

I have no idea just start, By the Way thanks
